# why won't my segue appear when it happens too close to another segue?

Tags: ios5, segue

I have an iOS app using a storyboard with a view controller that segues to two different modal view controllers.  One segue is triggered by a button and one's triggered by a timer.  They both work fine unless the button touch-up-inside and timer happen too close together.  If the segue from the button happens right before the segue from the timer, the segue from the button runs but the segue from the timer doesn't appear, even though prepareForSegue gets called.

Here's the prepareForSegue code,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueFromTimer"]) {        

        // Get destination view
        fromTimerViewController *vcTimer = [segue destinationViewController];

        // do some stuff
        // ...
    }

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"segueFromButton"]) { 

        // Get destination view
        fromButtonViewController *vcButton = [segue destinationViewController];

        // do some stuff
        // ...
     }
}
```

I can set breakpoints in prepareForSegue and see that it's getting called with id = segueFromTimer and that the destinationViewController looks valid, but the segueFromTimer segue never appears.